# How to display a grave accent in a textbox

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-2.0

On a postback I'm setting the value of one of my textboxes to a grave accent. This is causing a bunch of the HTML that follows to be shown in the textbox instead of the grave accent. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the HTML entity number or name instead of the actual grave accent character?  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Comment: ` is not on that page, but I've tried a few different encodings but it seems to go straight through as the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&#x0060;` for your grave accent. That should solve your problem.

Comment: If I do string.Replace("`"," &#x0060;") it will just output &#x0060; to the textbox